# saving the output of command line in a text file?

Tags: shell, scripting, io-redirection

I am using the following command line to analyse data:

```
unpackdcm -scr ${in} -targ ${out}
```

This command is printing on the screen status and description about the progress in the job. In order to save the status I did the following:

```
unpackdcm -scr ${in} -targ ${out} >stat.txt
```

But it did not work.

Comment: Try `unpackdcm -scr ${in} -targ ${out} | tee stat.txt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `>`-sign represents an [I/O-Redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html). With `>stat.txt` you redirect the standard output (stdout) of the application to the file `stat.txt`. It is redirected, so you will not see any output in the shell.

If you want the output in the current shell AND the file pipe the output into `tee`:

```
your_command | tee stat.txt
```

Or..

```
your_command | tee -a stat.txt
```

..to append to the file.

Your application may also produce some errors. They mostly occure in the standard error (see [standard streams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams)). To redirect that stream use the folloing syntax:

```
your_command 2>error.log
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the output is being sent to `stderr` which is not captured by the `>` operator which only captures `stdout`.

Instead, if you are using the bash shell, try routing `stderr` to `stdout` and into a file using the `&>` operator.
For example:

```
unpackdcm -scr ${in} -targ ${out} &>stat.txt
```

To redirect only `stderr`, use this:

```
unpackdcm -scr ${in} -targ ${out} 2>stat.txt
```